# Start a swiffy instance in an arbitrary element

Tags: javascript, google-swiffy

```
<script>var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.body, swiffyobject);</script>
<script>stage.start();</script>
```

Instead of `document.body` I want to start the swiffy object in `#front-slider`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the id is `front-slider` you can use the following line:

```
document.getElementById('front-slider')
```

which will return the element if found. Otherwise it will return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
#front-slider

<script>var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById("front-slider"), swiffyobject);</script>
<script>stage.start();</script>
```

Comment: No offence to your language, but please use English since Stackoverflow is an English speaking community regardless of your native language.